# Why is the time string returned by the cnosdb query different from the RFC3339 format of golang?

Tags: cnosdb, rfc3339

golang code：

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC().Format(time.RFC3339))
}
```

golang output：

```
2023-09-01T10:56:32+08:00
2023-09-01T02:56:32Z
```

cnosdb query result：

```
| cnosdb         | telegrafbfr   | 2023-09-01T02:15:00 | 0        | 1000    |
```

Does cnosdb have any considerations for this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, what is returned here is an closed RFC format.

https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/v2.3/reference/sql.html#data-types